# No Nautilus, Xterm, Terminal Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, xterm

I'm not sure what has recently changed for this to happen, but at the moment I can't open Terminal or the Nautilus file manager. Xterm was suggested on another forum as a way of checking some fixes, but when I try that, I get 'command not found'.

What's going on?! Thanks.

EDIT: I think this may be because of a Chrome Remote Desktop installation, however I can't find how to uninstall it and reset the configs. My sound is also outputting as Unix FIFO sink/...

Comment: What about Ctrl + alt + f1?

Comment: Seems like *xterm* is not installed. When you click on the activities button and type "xterm", there should be a button appearing on which you can click in order to install *xterm* via the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @StefanHamcke this worked, and I was able to uninstall Chrome Remote Desktop, which fixed everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the OP, *XTerm* serves as an alternative to the Gnome Terminal. If missing, it can be installed via *Ubuntu Software* by opening the Activities window (click the Activities button or press <kbd>Super</kbd>), typing `xterm`, and then clicking on the corresponding entry under *Ubuntu Software*.

Answer (score 1):

Removed ChromeRemoteDesktop and restarted. Everything is working fine now. Terminal, Nautilus, opening files and sound, which were not working before, have returned to the working state. I had been planning to installing Ubuntu 16.04 again, but thanks to this fix I saved myself the trouble of downgrading.

```
sudo apt remove --purge chrome-remote-desktop
```